# Update a record in the ZohoCRM using PHP SDK based on ID

Tags: php, laravel, api, zoho

I'm integrating the ZohoCRM PHP SDK with our Laravel 5 app (https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk) but I'm having trouble performing a simple update on a record.

I'm using this code to retrieve the record, and update it -

```
$record = \ZCRMRecord::getInstance('Products', $entityId);
$data = $record->getData();
if (count($data) > 0) {
       $record->setFieldValue('Product_Name', 'Test Update');
       $response = $record->update();
}
```

However, `$data` is always an empty array.

I have retrieved the `$entityId` variable by fetching records from the 'Products' module and storing the value from the `$record->getEntityId()` method e.g.

```
$records = \ZCRMModule::getInstance('Products')->getRecords()->getData();
if (count($records) > 0) {
       foreach ($records as $record) {
           $id = $record->getEntityId();
           // store id in RDS...
       }
}
```

I'm not sure if my method of fetching the record to update is incorrect or if my method of retrieving the record ID is incorrect.

Kind regards,

Phil

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the code is correct - the check for whether or not `$record->getData()` contains any items is not needed (it will always be empty).

In addition though I encountered errors due to this issue in using the SDK with PHP 7.2 - https://github.com/zoho/zcrm-php-sdk/pull/14

A manual change to the `ZohoHTTPConnector` class is required until this pull request is merged.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to update the record

```
$apiResponse=ZCRMModule::getInstance('Products')->getRecord($entityId);
$record = $apiResponse->getData(); 
$record->setFieldValue('Product_Name', 'Test Update');
$response = $record->update();
```